Am having setter error in Object Box flutter for a nested relationship
The setter 'target' isn't defined for the type 'LocationModel'.
Try importing the library that defines 'target', correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'target'.
below is my code
      // Handle current location
      if (profileJson.containsKey('current_location')) {
        final currentLocationJson =
            profileJson['current_location'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final currentLocationModel =
            LocationModel.fromJson(currentLocationJson);

        /!! Error here 
        profileModel.currentLocation.target = currentLocationModel;
      }

      // Handle home town
      if (profileJson.containsKey('home_town')) {
        final hometownJson = profileJson['home_town'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final hometownModel = LocationModel.fromJson(hometownJson);

        /!! Error here
        profileModel.homeTown.target = hometownModel;
      }

      **/** No error with this one **/**
      profileModel.userModel.target = userModel;


My model example
class LocationModel extends Equatable {
  @Id()
  int id;

  final String? city;
  final String? country;
  final String? latitude;
  final String? longitude;

  LocationModel({
    this.id = 0,
    this.city,
    this.country,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
  });
final currentLocation = ToOne<UserProfileModel>();

final homeTown = ToOne<UserProfileModel>();


my profile model
class UserProfileModel extends Equatable {
  @Id()
  int id;

  @JsonKey(name: 'avatar_url')
  final String? avatarUrl;

  @JsonKey(name: 'current_location')
  @Transient()
  final LocationModel? currentLocation;

  @JsonKey(name: 'home_town')
  @Transient()
  final LocationModel? homeTown;

final userModel = ToOne<UserModel>();

  UserProfileModel({
    this.id = 0,


This looks like the LocationModel and UserProfileModel are mixed up. Both of them have a currentLocation field. But one has type ToOne<UserProfileModel>, the other of LocationModel?.
Only the ToOne has the target method.

No it's not a mix up i have marked the one in user profile with @Transient() to be ignored
